# query a table in mysql which does not have primary key

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

I am new to database, and run into a time issue when querying a table where no field is indicated as primary key.

for example

+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |

+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| a_id      | char(10) | NO   |     |         |       |

| media      | char(3)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

| label     | char(37) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

---

As you can see, no of the field have any key specification. When I do a query like
"select label from table where a_id=?", the query is extremely slow. Is this caused by the lack of primary key?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

No, it is caused by lack of indexes. A primary key must contain a unique and non-null value. If you add an index on the column, it may contain duplicates, but your query will still be faster.

If you want the field to be unique, but you don't want it to be a primary key (although you should wonder why), you can even add a unique index. It will force the value to be unique, but it's no primary key.

That can be convenient when you want the table to have an id and a description that should both be unique. Usually you'll make the id the primary key, and the description just unique.